Where to buy a Sony cyber shot dsc w90 door from?
I just bought my first ever digital camera. A Sony cyber shot dsc w90 but it’s missing the door/battery cover and I’m not sure where to buy one from any suggestions?

Check ebay for part/repair cameras, or do like they used to and fake it with duct tape and something metal. A large fraction of point-and-shoots don't get repaired (my local shop has a grain bin full of dead point-and shoots for some morbid reason) so there just may be no parts cameras being sold.

Stupid question.  But did the seller disclose that the door was missing?

It's a 2007 camera. Parts will be hard to find from "official" sources. They may be hard to find even from salvagers on eBay.

The good news is that there are still plenty of third party NP-BG1 batteries available for it, and chargers for the NP-BG1 batteries as well.
